# Multiple call of Axios.all requests from an array with multiple links

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

`data1` is an array with 5 links from the below loop.

```
let data1 = [];
console.log(data1);

for (let Items of ItemsArray) {
  const row = {
    PricingSummary: Items.pricingOptionsSummaryUrl,
  }
  data1.push(row);
  };
```

I want to use this array to perform 5 times GET requests by using `Axios.all`.
After getting the response, I want to setState to map with the data I want.

```
const callprice = () => { //assign a variable for a call function
    Axios.all(data1.map(l => Axios.get(l)))
    .then(Axios.spread(function(...res) {
      // setStats(....)
      console.log(res); // Getting error message : xhr.js:210 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
    }));
};
```

I'm getting the localhost 404 (Not Found) errors. Believe the request array links are incorrect from the `data1`, but not sure how to make them correct.

Example of the console for the `data1`:

```
0: {PricingSummary: 'http://snapshot.dellsvc/snapshots/MXL5hLvzBkajQ-fqGTo9oA'}
1: {PricingSummary: 'http://snapshot.dellsvc/snapshots/3gmDYxoCg0m9YgWB3aLLpA'}
2: {PricingSummary: 'http://snapshot.dellsvc/snapshots/dEpCHAi3IUe1sTIqEo9Idw'}
3: {PricingSummary: 'http://snapshot.dellsvc/snapshots/SAIS_lcIxU202-Mnm5KLIQ'}
4: {PricingSummary: 'http://snapshot.dellsvc/snapshots/H_9txy3Ejkm-zoe49Hbkzg'}
5: {PricingSummary: undefined}
```

Comment: Axios.all and Axios.spread are both deprecated. Why is your last URL `undefined`? Surely that's a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `axios.all()` and `axios.spread()` are [both deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042). You should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead.

Second, it seems at least one of your URLs is `undefined` which definitely won't work in a request. You may want to filter out these problem records.

Third, you're pushing objects with a `PricingSummary` property into `data1`. These cannot be used in `axios.get()` since it expects a URL **string**, not an object. This is where your `[object%20Object]` is coming from.

```js
const callprice = async () => {
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    ItemsArray
      .filter(item => item.pricingOptionsSummaryUrl) // remove falsy values
      .map(async (item) => (await axios.get(item.pricingOptionsSummaryUrl)).data) 
  )

  // now `responses` is an array of the response data
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly!@Phil, ok! I've to define the URLs first into just the `string` and without the `object` in order to work by the Axios request. I'm very new to Axios, I should study more on this, anyway thank you!

Answer (score -3):

You shoud use Promise.allSettled instead