# How to call api parallelly in react using axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, axios

I've list of Id's in an array, so I would like to pass each id to api end point, to get that particular id's information, so I want to do this in a parallel way instead of one by one call,
So I'm using axios and also if there is a 1000 id's as batch I want to call 100 id's parallely, and again rest 100 id's, Can anyone suggest me the solution for this approach.

Here is the code:

```
  const getApiResponse=(gitIds)=>{
         let responseArray=[];
         return listOfIds?.map((listId)=>{

            const fetcServiceData = async (): Promise<void> => {
              return api.get(`api-end-point/${listId}`);
            }; 
            fetcServiceData()
            .then((value:any) => {
                const  response={
                    studentName: value.name,
                    grade: value.grade,
                }
                responseArray=[...responseArray,response]
               return responseArray
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
              })
          return responseArray;
        })
 
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple call of Axios.all requests from an array with multiple links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163950/multiple-call-of-axios-all-requests-from-an-array-with-multiple-links)

Comment: So, so far your code does nothing to batch your requests in batches of 100. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create multiple promises and push them in an array and use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve all of them together.

`Keep in mind that Promise.all rejects as soon as any of those promises is rejected with the first error message.`

Example:

```
const promise1 = fetchServiceData();
const promise2 = fetchServiceData();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(response => {
    const promise1Response = response[0];
    const promise2Response = response[1];

    // Do something with these responses.

}).catch(err => {
    // Do something with the error
});
```

Comment: Hi, Suppose if I have 2000 records, I have to declare that many const right? is it a good approach?

Comment: You could do it in a loop and process records in small batches of 20-50 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like this pattern of chaining promises, returning them to keep the promise chain alive.

Like this:

```
axios
  .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=' + this.props.p1)
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ p1Location: response.data });
    return axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=' + this.props.p2);
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ p2Location: response.data });
    return axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=' + this.props.p3);
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ p3Location: response.data });
  }).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

Comment: That will take longer time to get all data.

Comment: I think it's okay to do because it'll server the purpose.

Comment: But , is it calling the api paralelly? and how to pass 100 batch at one time and rest of id's in other batch?

Comment: Yes You can parse like this:

const reqOne = axios.get(endpoint);
const reqTwo = axios.get(endpoint);

axios.all([reqOne, reqTwo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const responseOne = responses[0]
  const responseTwo = responses[1]
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise
  .all(/* list of async calls */)
  .then(doSomethingWithTheResults)
```

will do what you want.

However, in the unlikely event that you are actually doing this, you should ask yourself the question, why am I clogging up my request line?

Say I'm asking for 10k records...

asynchronously...

to my server...

and 10 users do the same...

Won't that take an awful long time? Am I doing a hidden DDoS attack with my own code?

A more preferred way to counter this problem is to add an API endpoint in which you can give an amount of ids that return you the data you need.

```
const fetchServiceData = async (listIds: string[]): Promise<ListItem[]> => {
  return api.get(`api-end-point?listids=${listIds.join(',')}`);
};
```